# Easy way to get rows of database into an associative array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

Is there an easier way to get a couple of rows of a mysql-database in an associative array than this:

```
 $a_companylist = array();
 $a_companies = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id, fullname FROM companies WHERE stockactive = 1");
 while($a_company = mysqli_fetch_assoc($a_companies)){
  $a_companylist[$a_company['id']] = $a_company['fullname'];
 }
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: No, you've made it as small as possible given that you return multiple rows from your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) is not only a more contemporary approach than mysqli, but it gives you also the advantage of something like this:

```
$a_company_list = $pdo->query("SELECT ...")->fetchAll();
```

Have look a the examples in the php doc:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: That should be `->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP)`